# Passport.js async vs sync deserialization

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, passport.js

I'm implementing a payment feature on my app, and my provider requres `AccountId` (identification of the user in my system) and `Email`. I've noticed some strange behaviour I cannot explain with Passport.js. First of all, deserialization looks like in docs:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Now, I get that this is an async operation, however when I form the data for the request, I do:

```
var data = {
    AccountId: toString(req.user._id),
    Email: req.user.auth.local.email
    // ...
}
```

For some reason `Email` gets set correctly, but `AccountId` always returns `[object Undefined]`. Well, I thought that maybe it's due to Passport's async nature of deserialization (since it requires time to `User.findById()`), but why does `Email` gets set correctly then?

I've found a way of setting `AccountId` to `req.session.passport.user`, but it seems like a hack to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
AccountId: toString(req.user._id),
```

toString is a method of an object. In the browser, simply calling toString assumes that you mean `window.toString()` and it returns `[object Window]`. In Node, since the global window does not exist, you get `[object Undefined]`.

I *think* the way you meant to call that function would be like so:

```
 AccountId: req.user._id.toString(),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is indeed the way I meant to use it!

Comment: Still I don't get the situation with `User.findById()`, it should be async. Does it mean that Node waits for it to get resolved and processes the code in next loops?

Comment: @AntonEgorov You're correct, `User.findById()` is async. Express does not start running your route handling code until after the middleware has called the `done` function, which you do _after_ `User.findById()` has returned in the callback.